# Resolving Resource Strings

Tags: c#, .net, internationalization, resources, resourcemanager

I have a single resource file (*.resx*) that defines the following languages:

1. `neutral` - International English as the default/fallback language
2. `en-US`   - Sparsely populated for words like colour/color
3. `de`      - German translations

To get a resource string I am using the 'System.Resources.ResourceManager(Type resourceSource)` as follows:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en");
var resourceManager = new ResourceManager(resourceType);
var translatedString = rm.GetString("FavouriteColour", culture)
```

When I call the above with the culture set to `en-GB` I get the default/neutral resource value of *"Favourite Colour"* as expected, but if I specify the culture as simply `en` I get the `en-US` resource value of *"Favourite Color"*

Why does the ResourceManager resolve the neutral `en` language to the `en-US` variant and is there any way to stop this behaviour?

Comment: The [Resource Fallback Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb6a8618(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_1) explains what is happening. And what do you mean by "stop this behavior"? Do you mean you don't want a resource resolved at all if there is not an exact culture match?

Comment: "Stop this" was badly phrased, but I had expected that if I asked explicitly for the neutral version of the language, in the case 'en' then I would have either received that that version, if defined, or it would have fallen back to the default/neutral definition in the resource.  I did not expect 'en' to translate to 'en-US'.